# Unable to interact with facebook's graph API using node.js

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is the url I am trying to hit:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=friends?access_token=xxxx.
```

Expected result : (as on Graph API Explorer):

```
{
  "friends": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 648
    }
  },
  "id": "xxxx"
}
```

Call to get number of friends :(node.js)

```
fb.getFbData(constants.AccessToken, 'me?fields=friends', function(data){
        res.send(data);
    });
```

Method to fetch number of friends:(node.js)

```
var https = require('https');
    exports.getFbData = function(accessToken, apiPath, callback) {
        var options = {
            host: 'graph.facebook.com',
            port: 443,
            path: apiPath + '?access_token=' + accessToken, //apiPath example: '/me/friends'
            method: 'GET'
        };

        console.log("\n\n options:::", options);
        var buffer = ''; //this buffer will be populated with the chunks of the data received from facebook
        var request = https.get(options, function(result){
            result.setEncoding('utf8');
            result.on('data', function(chunk){
                buffer += chunk;
            });

            result.on('end', function(){
                callback(buffer);
            });
        });

        request.on('error', function(e){
            console.log('error from facebook.getFbData: ' + e.message)
        });

        request.end();
    }
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: You are messing up the query string. It _starts_ with a question mark, and then uses an ampersand to separate the name=value pairs from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did 2 things wrong:

1. Improper URL , second parameter that was being passed was without '&' in URL.
2. When using https.get with 'options' like this call:

   var options = {
               host: 'graph.facebook.com',
               port: 443,
               path: apiPath + '?access_token=' + accessToken, 
               method: 'GET'
           };

Then, 'host' gets appended in the URL and therefore the 'path' only needs to contain the directory on the website. eg: /v2.8/me?fields=friends